# How can I connect to my ACT database to export data?

Tags: sql-server, act

I am trying to export data from an MSSQL server that ACT uses. It is ACT 2005. I have tried tons of different things, from trying to starting the MSSQL server in single user mode (still can't login), I have tried copying the mdf files from it and putting it on another server (it complains about having the same name as another database for master.mdf and almost every other file), I have tried putting Administrator in the group that the MSSQL instance runs under, and nothing seems to work! Can anybody with experience with this help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Single-user mode should do what you need.

Comment: What version of SQL Server 2005 are you working with? The master.mdf is not the application database, that is a system database for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

ACT secure the DB to prevent access by anything other than it's own tools.  They have a procedure on their site whereby you can request access to a tool that will provide you with the account credentials - I think they try to specify some usage constraints that you can only use the account to enable your own backups outside of ACTs tools.

... but in an previous job we used it to allow us to query customer data for use within another application and it worked pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the File|Export|Text File function.

Comment: I don't think this is going to help much if he can't login to the DB.